# How to make a linear layout expand on tap showing less colapsed

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

If I have a linear layout with vertical orientation and e.g. 6 children layouts what is the standard way to make it into a tappable layout?
I.e. Show only 2 of the children and on tap expand to show all?
I can think of having 2 layouts one with 2 children and 1 with 6 and hide/show each one alternatively on tap.
Is there a more standard way?

Answer (score 0):

Standard way to do it by using [Expandable ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).
You can find a working example [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

It look like this

[image]

Comment: This is useful but not exactly what I had in mind. I need to show 2 elements and then expand to show all. This is header and list

Comment: Yes. It is a header that expands the list.